# SDL2 empty transparent window in Linux

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Here is some sample SDL2 code I tried to run on my Linux computer running Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma Desktop Environment (I have multiple desktop environments installed in case it is relevant):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        std::cerr << "SDL_Init() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Hello world",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640,480,
        0
    );

    if(win == nullptr){
        std::cerr << "SDL_CreateWindow() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;  
    }

    //Create and init the renderer
    SDL_Renderer* ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 0);
    if(ren == nullptr){
        std::cerr << "SDL_CreateRenderer() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        return 1;
    }

    //Render something
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(ren,640,480);

    //Set colour of renderer
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren,255,0,0,255);

    //Clear the screen to the set colour
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);

    //Show all the has been done behind the scenes
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    //Delay so that we can see what is on the screen
    SDL_Delay(5000);

    //Clean Up
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

The red window that is supposed to appear appears only once when I run the program for the first time. All subsequent executions produce an empty transparent window with whatever is in the background. The background image drags along with the window.

I have tried `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` flag in `SDL_CreateWindow()` as well as `SDL_RENDER_ACCELERATED` flag for `SDL_CreateRenderer()`.

The only way to produce the red screen again is to reboot the system.

I even compiled and ran this with an IDE (CodeLite) and I still got the same results.

This particular question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227698/sdl2-window-not-showing) shows similar problems. But the OP isn't using Linux and the problem isn't exactly the same.

Other posts on this website mention event processing but I haven't gotten that far. If at all it is necessary, I would be grateful for some resources on it as the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) doesn't explain much.

**Update**:This program runs fine on another computer running Lubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `SDL_Delay()` (which blocks all event processing like notifying X11/Wayland & your window manager that your process is still alive) with a loop that calls [`SDL_PumpEvents()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) somehow, either directly (like below) or indirectly via `SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_WaitEvent()`:

```
const Uint32 startMs = SDL_GetTicks();
while( SDL_GetTicks() - startMs < 5000 )
{
    SDL_PumpEvents();

    //Render something
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(ren,640,480);

    //Set colour of renderer
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren,255,0,0,255);

    //Clear the screen to the set colour
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);

    //Show all the has been done behind the scenes
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
}
```

All together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) != 0 )
    {
        std::cerr << "SDL_Init() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow
        (
        "Hello world",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640, 480,
        0
        );

    if( win == nullptr )
    {
        std::cerr << "SDL_CreateWindow() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Create and init the renderer
    SDL_Renderer* ren = SDL_CreateRenderer( win, -1, 0 );
    if( ren == nullptr )
    {
        std::cerr << "SDL_CreateRenderer() Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow( win );
        return 1;
    }

    const Uint32 startMs = SDL_GetTicks();
    while( SDL_GetTicks() - startMs < 5000 )
    {
        SDL_PumpEvents();

        //Render something
        SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize( ren, 640, 480 );

        //Set colour of renderer
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( ren, 255, 0, 0, 255 );

        //Clear the screen to the set colour
        SDL_RenderClear( ren );

        //Show all the has been done behind the scenes
        SDL_RenderPresent( ren );
    }

    //Clean Up
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( ren );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( win );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy Lord it works! Could you point me to some resources where I could read more about this?

Comment: @DS2830: The general concept is an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop): The OS/windowing system delivers events (input, timers, "hey I need you to redraw your part of the screen") to your application and your application needs to say "OK, got it" for each event in a timely manner (i.e., don't block for 5 seconds in a `sleep()` :)) or else the system thinks your program has died or become otherwise unresponsive.

Comment: Also, we use a sort of makeshift approach in this case instead of something the library intends for us to use(obviously because it was required). Would such a thing be reasonable to do in real-world software? Why or why not?

Comment: @DS2830: The "splat stuff to screen, sleep for 5s, then exit" sequence you're using I've really only seen in [the SDL test programs](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/c005c49beaa9/test); "Real" applications will use a proper `SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_WaitEvent()` event loop to react to user input & re-draw.