# SDL fails to display image?

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

My code doesn't display anything. All I get is a window with no image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

SDL_Window *gWindow=NULL;
SDL_Surface *gScreenSurface=NULL;
SDL_Surface *gHelloWorld=NULL;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH=640, SCREEN_HEIGHT=480;
bool init(){
    bool success = true;

    if(SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error : %s \n", SDL_GetError() );
        success=false;
    }
    else{
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow ( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL ){
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success=false;
        }
        else {
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface (gWindow);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

bool loadMedia(){
    bool success=true;

    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP ( "hello_world.bmp" );
    if (gHelloWorld == NULL ){
        printf( "Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n", "hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError() );
        success=false;
    }
    return success;
}

void close(){
    SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
    gHelloWorld=NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow=NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    if(!init()){
        printf( "failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else {
        if( !loadMedia() ) {
            printf ("failed to laod media! \n");
        }
        else {
            SDL_BlitSurface( gHelloWorld, NULL, SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow), NULL );
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface ( gWindow );
            SDL_Delay (2000);
        }
    }
    close();
```

I expect it to show me a bmp image which is in the path specified here in the `loadBMP()` function but all I get is an empty transparent window.

I am using KDE Konsole, if that has to do something with this.

Comment: Do you get your `"Unable to load image %s! SDL Error: %s\n"` error message on console?

Comment: Have you tried a different .bmp file?  Your code worked fine for me after I installed sdl2 and compiled with `clang++ main.cpp \`sdl2-config --libs\``.  Also, I'm assuming your image is in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: I don't, thats why I mentioned about that KDE desktop environment if there is some deeper issue

Comment: And yeah my image file is there

Comment: If you're not sure whether diagnostic output is done properly, you may check in debugger whether error branch is entered. However, did you try (at least temporarily) with the absolute path of image? (I suspect that your current dir. in your app. is not what you expect.)

Comment: By the way I am using `g++`, not `clang++`

Comment: I cannot imagine that `g++` vs. `clang++` has an effect on this... ;-)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7Tgq4Bw.png

Comment: A screenshot with the directory contents listed there and options I used

Comment: Did you try your program with absolute image file path (for testing)?

Comment: like "/home/user/projects/hello_world.bmp" ? Yeah I did

Comment: May be, convert it to PNG and try with this. (I googled a bit and found e.g. [SO: Displaying an .bmp image in C++/SDL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216338/displaying-an-bmp-image-in-c-sdl2) which linked to [SO: How to load JPG/PNG Textures in an SDL/OpenGL App under OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41686559/7478597).)

Comment: Maybe try setting all the pixels to white manually after it's loaded?  I'm able to do so with adding this just before the return statement in loadMedia:
`uint8_t *pixels = (uint8_t*)gHelloWorld->pixels;
for(auto i =0; i < gHelloWorld->w * gHelloWorld->h; ++i)
 pixels[i] = 0;`

FYI: This may not be the proper way to do it, as I don't use SDL2 very often.  If it turns white, you have an issue with the bmp data.  If it doesn't, then the picture is probably fine and perhaps it's something to do with your SDL initialization.

Comment: You should have proper update loop and redraw when window manager asks you to (or just redraw unconditionally). Draw&delay is not a way to display things.

Comment: I've run your code and it works!, anyway I recommend you change close() function by w_close or other name, for some compilers close is a reserved word.
`g++ main.cpp -lSDL2`

Comment: @MiguelÁngelRetamozoSanchez: I *think* that's only an issue with C compilers or if you declare `close()` as `extern "C"` so that C++ doesn't name-mangle it into the default file- or translation-unit-local anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 2):

KDE eh?  Plasma [composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) by default; try disabling compositing or add [a proper event-handling loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047881/44729) so your process has a chance to handle repaint events.